# Overlay an image with an opacity setting in Ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, opacity

- I want to overlay an image with an opacity setting
- I know how to overlay an image on a video, but I don’t understand how to set its opacity level too. I can easily add a watermark on my video, but this watermark is on opacity 100%:
- But how do I make the image file have an opacity of 50%?

  Example:   `ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -i image.png -af "pan=stereo|c0<c0+c2|c1<c1+c3,aeval=val(0)|val(1),volume=1.6" -vf "opacity=0.5" out.mp4`

> [AVFilterGraph @ 0000000000316dc0] No such filter: 'opacity'
> Error opening filters!

Comment: What's your reason for using `pan=stereo|c0<c0+c2|c1<c1+c3,aeval=val(0)|val(1)`? I see this or similar variants often, but nobody knows why they add it.

Comment: That 's just an example :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the command below.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -i image.png \
-af "pan=stereo|c0<c0+c2|c1<c1+c3,aeval=val(0)|val(1),volume=1.6" \
-filter_complex "[1]geq=r='r(X,Y)':a='0.5*alpha(X,Y)'[a];[0][a]overlay" out.mp4
```

The `a='0.5*alpha(X,Y)'` sets the alpha i.e. opacity.

The `geq` filter doesn't autodetect whether the input is RGB or YUV and takes its cue from the presence of an expression of one of the non-alpha planes, so one of those has to be specified. I've specified an expression for the R plane and set it to identity, so it isn't altered.

Comment: I tried , but the picture does not show opacity

Comment: Show the full console output. Add it to the Q.

Comment: Hey @Mulvya, I want to add commands to crop video and video formats , but it is an error that I do not get treated , you can help me? : ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -i image.png -af "pan=stereo|c0<c0+c2|c1<c1+c3,aeval=val(0)|val(1),volume=1.6" -filter_complex "**crop=iw/1.3:ih/1.3,scale=640:480**,[1]geq=r='r(X,Y)':a='0.5*alpha(X,Y)'[a];[0][a]overlay" out.mp4 ///===> Error: [AVFilterGraph @ 00000000027af4c0] Too many inputs specified for the "geq" filter.
Error initializing complex filters.

Comment: Use `-filter_complex "[0]crop=iw/1.3:ih/1.3,scale=640:480[base];[1]geq=r='r(X,Y)':a='0.5*alpha(X,Y)'[a];[base][a]‌​overlay"`

Comment: Hey @Mulvya, it is faulty: **[AVFilterGraph @ 00000000004b3760] No such filter: 'ΓÇîΓÇïoverlay'
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument**

Comment: Looks like your command is either malformed or your ffmpeg does not have overlay.

Comment: I have tried but failed on:////===> D:\ffmpeg\bin
>ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -i image.png -af "pan=stereo|c0<c0+c2|c1<c1+c3,aeval=val(0)|va
l(1),volume=1.6" -filter_complex "[0]crop=iw/1.3:ih/1.3,scale=640:480[base];[1]g
eq=r='r(X,Y)':a='0.5*alpha(X,Y)'[??a];[base][a]??overlay" output.mp4
...... Input #1, png_pipe, from 'image.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 640x480 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 4:3], 25 tbr,
25 tbn, 25 tbc
[AVFilterGraph @ 0000000002708f00] No such filter: 'ΓÇîΓÇïoverlay'
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument

Comment: What's `[??a]` and `??overlay` ? `??` should not be there,

Comment: I don't understand , so any solution has to do the job as above ?

Comment: Check the command you posted. There's `??` in there.